# What hg command displays only heads that are incoming?

Tags: mercurial, head, pull

I have a two repositories, I'll call them `RepoA` and `RepoB`. `RepoA` has many changesets that the other is lacking. There are many heads in `RepoA` and only a few in `RepoB`. I'd like a command that tells me only the heads that will be added to `RepoB` after an hg pull.

I need this because I want to leave some of the heads in `RepoA` behind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the repo that you want to pull, try this command:

```
hg log -r "outgoing('path\to\your\repo') and head()"
```

If you can't run that on the repo you want to pull from directly, then clone it local and run it on the clone.

head() is defined as "Changeset is a named branch head", so if the heads you are interested in aren't named branches, I'm not sure if this will work.

Check out hg help revset for more info.

Comment: Thanks, this did exactly what I wanted. I'll probably be using this a lot in the future.

Answer (score 1):

The command `hg incoming` has a `-b` parameter for a specific branch. Perhaps that's what you need in this case.